# HTML website with Knockoutjs bindings has performance issue

Tags: azure, knockout.js, datatables

I am working on my client's pure HTML CSS website having data bindings with JSON datasets using Knockoutjs. For tables I have used Datatables library.

I have hosted the website on Windows Azure websites.

Here is the link of website : http://bit.ly/(REMOVED SINCE IT IS CONFEDENTIAL)

It takes around 4 seconds to load the website even though I have used CDN for common JS libraries.

It should not have that much load time. I am unable to find the culprit here. I am fetching data from 4 different datasets. Does it impact on performance? Or there is problem with Windows Azure datacenter, It takes while to get response from Azure server. Is Azure culprit?

You can examine the page load time on the website link given above.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution :**

Instead of using sync calls, used

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
 //whole knockoutjs logic and bindings
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, according to Chrome, it takes about 800ms-900ms for me to load the full page. There's one 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All model .js files (starting with `patientMedicationChart-Index.js`) are loaded synchronously (`async:false` is set in that file). This means that the browser has to wait for each script file to be loaded before continuing to load the next.

I count about 10 files loaded like that for your demo, which (for me) each take about 200ms to load (about 95% of that 200ms is spent waiting for a response, which also seems rather slow; that might be a server issue with Azure). So times 10 is already 2 seconds spent loading those files, and only after loading all of them will the `ready` event for the page be triggered.

There might be a reason for wanting to load those files synchronously, but as it is, it's causing a significant part of the loading time for the entire page.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. So probably there is an issue with Azure server as well. Since waiting time is around 100-200ms for each request. If I consider 10 requests, it will take around 1.5 seconds extra. 

I can try relocating server closer to the location where the website will be used. 

Well, is there any way where I can get json datasets asynchronously?

Comment: AJAX requests are asynchronous by default (unless that's turned off, like in your code), but it would require a rewrite of your JS code since dealing with such requests is completely different from handling synchronous requests.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have started rewriting the javascript :-) Appreciate your help.